# !sad throws error: "TypeError: Cannot read property of 'members' of undefined"

Tags: discord.io

The startup of the bot works but when I call the command `!sad` in discord, I get an error saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined'`

```js
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');
// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
  colorize: true
});
logger.level = 'debug';

// Initialize Discord Bot
var bot = new Discord.Client({
  token: auth.token,
  autorun: true
});

bot.on('ready', function(evt) {
  logger.info('Connected');
  logger.info('Logged in as: ');
  logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');
});

bot.on('message', function(user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
  if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
    var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
    var cmd = args[0];

    args = args.splice(1);
    switch (cmd) {

      case 'sad':
        message.guild.members.get("NotSaltShaker93#8606").kick();
        bot.sendMessage({
          to: channelID,
          message: 'ET has been kicked'
        });
        break;

    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, I'm replacing the `discord.js`tag with `discord.io`, since that is the library you're using :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was utilizing the wrong command for this it should have been:

```
bot.kick('415286393062031361');
```